# PHP v/s JSP (on the basis of security)

Tags: php, security, jsp

I'm a beginner web developer knows both [`PHP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and [`JSP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) coding formats

I found lots pages on internet the all told that `PHP` is less secure than `JSP`.
but they all almost are old pages may be updated 2-3 years ago. Here I'm referring some forum links

[Is JSP a good alternative to PHP [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110362/is-jsp-a-good-alternative-to-php)
[ASP - PHP - JSP ... which is better?](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/148885/asp-php-jsp-...-which-is-better)

Now as every year new version `PHP` are releasing with lots of new features Like OOP, PHP Filters etc.

My question is that  is `PHP` still less secure than `JSP`? if yes, than i want to know that what facts that makes `PHP` less secure than `JSP`. Please explain with examples if possible.

**According to my opinion**, It's the developer(means developer's code) who's responsible for security. 
But i still want to know other programmers opinions

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: I am satisfied with your opinion that developer's code matter more than the architecture of scripting language.

Comment: OOP ? PHP Filters ? That's 10 years ago!

Comment: Pro-Java argument (from a PHP guy!): PHP compiles at runtime, which makes it "easier" for an attacker to really run infiltrated code on the server (for example when an uploaded avatar image contains in fact php code). Compiling infiltrated Java is not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

"**According to my opinion, It's the developer(means developer's code) who's responsible for security**"

Smart programming languages add up more layers which most of the time is in price of performance. Much of security on web applications is checking client input (uploaded file, form entries, URL...) to be same as expected. Smart languages do much of the work automatically. Also they have built-in security schemes which are prone to bug if you write them yourself.

I believe security is not the main concern for selecting the platform but should be considered besides performance, budget, maintenance...

Note: Security is not just about web application programming, you may get hacked from upper layers like other applications on the same web server, at operating system level...